# Qt Creator: Design changes not showing when run

Tags: qt

I had made some changes on the '**mainwindow.ui**' file from the folder: 'Forms'. 
I've added a new title entitled 'File' and there only two simple options, 'Add Fractal' and 'Exit'

[image]

You can also see that both are on the mainwindow.ui file:[image]

But when I run the project, the window is not showing as I wish. Tabs are not showing.

[image]

I had build, rebuild and make, and still have this strange thing.
Can anyone give me a hand?

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    void createActions();
    void createMenus();
    // Widgets i layouts
    QWidget *centralWidget;
    // Accions associades als menus
    QAction *exitAct;
    // Menus principals
    QMenu *fileMenu;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    centralWidget = new QWidget;
    setCentralWidget(centralWidget); createActions();
    createMenus();
    setWindowTitle(tr("Practica 1: GiVD 2011-2012"));
    resize(640, 480);
}

void MainWindow::createActions() {
    exitAct = new QAction(tr("&Exit"), this);
    exitAct->setShortcut(tr("Ctrl+Q"));
    exitAct->setStatusTip(tr("Sortir del programa"));
    connect(exitAct, SIGNAL(triggered()), qApp, SLOT(closeAllWindows()));
}

void MainWindow::createMenus()
{
    fileMenu = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("&File"));
    fileMenu->addSeparator();
    // Per a cada nou submenú has de fer un addAction
    fileMenu->addAction(exitAct);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget"/>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>400</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuFile">
    <property name="title">
     <string>File</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="actionAdd_Fractal"/>
    <addaction name="actionExit"/>
   </widget>
   <addaction name="menuFile"/>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
  <action name="actionAdd_Fractal">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Add Fractal</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionExit">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Exit</string>
   </property>
  </action>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: I personally don't use Qt Creator, but are you sure that UIC gets run on your .ui file? And does the generated header file update?

Comment: How can I know that? Im sorry Bart but I'm now with the Qt Creator and C++. At least, on the .pro file I have 'FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
'

Comment: From what I understand (but someone else might correct me) adding the .ui to FORMS should ensure that UIC is being called. This should generate a .h file with a similar name, containing the C++ code to set up your GUI. Have a look if such a file is indeed generated and is part of your project.

Comment: Show to us the MainWindow class definition (in .h file) and the MainWindow constructor (in .cpp file).

Comment: On the 'build' folder appears that new .h with the name 'ui_mainwindow.h' . I can read the tabs on the code, but they are not showing. I've delete it so it can re-make again, but still doesnt work.

Comment: @borges - the message is now edited and you can see the Mainwindow.h and the mainwindow.cpp.

Comment: MainWindow::createActions() and MainWindow::createMenus() shouldn't be necessary if you using an ui-file which creates the same actions/menus.

Comment: It's not necessary but it should work with it..

Comment: Could you post your main.cpp and your mainwindow.ui too?

Comment: @user963658 works like expected (linux, qt4.6, 2 menu entries "File" and so on).

Comment: I'm using OSX, maybe that's the problem? Is there anything I have to do to run this in OSX?

Comment: I'm betting that you need to use the "run qmake" option too.  QtCreator really should do that automatically when it changes the .pro file (like when adding a new file), but it doesn't seem to always do that and thus the Make dependencies don't get updated.

Comment: Stupid question: Did you check, that your menu does not appear in menu bar on the top of the screen?

Comment: Nevermind, works perfect on Linux so gonna leave OSX and start working on Linux for Qt Creator. Thanks to all the people who tried to give me a hand!

Answer (score 1):

I got into the same issue until I realized that menu's on a mac OS appear at the top and not at the application window.

See if this is the case for you.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with all changes in the `.ui` file, not only tabs.
All the changes are saved in the `.ui` file, then qmake reran, but it still shows some old `.ui` variant that is not even in the *src* folder already.

It was because I built my project through Visual Studio.
I've noticed, that running a project in Visual Studio before closing Qt Designer may cause it. Even opening it back in Qt Creator didn't help.

The only thing that helped was deleting all Visual Studio files from the project folder.