# Qt Creator not showing .ui changes when run

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qt-designer

Similar to this question: [Qt Creator: Design changes not showing when run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467796/qt-creator-design-changes-not-showing-when-run)

I cannot make a simple change in the UI and then see it when I run.  I've tried adding a dummy label and push button.  No matter how much I edit the `MainWindow.ui` file, I can not get the UI to change.  The ui_MainWindow.h file also does not change.  It seems like whatever is supposed to generate that file is not being run.

I've tried cleaning before I run.  I've tried unchecking the 'Shadow build' option under Projects >> Build & Run >> General >> Shadow build checkbox and then restarting Qt Creator.  I've tried restarting my PC and then testing.  That damn ui_xxx file will not update!

Host OS: Windows 7, 64b
Qt Creator version: 3.0.1 based on QT 5.2.1 (MSVC 2010, 32 bit), built on Jan 31 2014

Comment: If you delete the ui_MainWindow.h from the build directory it should be regenerated the next time you run qmake (QtCreator should do that automatically)

Comment: In Creator, there is a preview under Forms/Preview. Does that show the differences?

Comment: Have you tried _Run qmake_?

Comment: @Zlatomir, Where would i run a command line? How can execute that? I'm pretty new to Qt.

Comment: You can find that in the _Build_ menu in Qt Creator

Comment: @ExpatEgghead, Forms is not a toolbar item in Qt5.  I have a Forms logical directory in the 'Projects' inspector.  My MainWindow.ui lives there and I can open that fine and add buttons and such, but these do not show up.

Comment: Good point @TimMeyer, but even though I delete the ui_MainWindow.h, clean project, run qmake on project, I still can't generate a new ui_MainWindow.h and the application still runs as it did before!  Yes, I am looking in the correct directory.

Comment: Hm no clue then. You should have a "qmake" option available when right-clicking your project in the "Edit" area in Qt Creator though

Comment: possibly your answer  : http://stackoverflow.com/a/15616946/2736559

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382652/qt-designer-does-not-update-the-gui

Answer (score 13):

One reason for this buggy behavior is the Shadow build checkbox is enabled. Click on the "Project" icon in the Qt creator, under Build-> General, uncheck Shadow build. Rebuild again and run.

Answer (score 1):

After modifying UI elements on a project what worked for me was to delete the directory:  {project dir}/GeneratedFiles followed by a project rebuild.

UI elements including menu changes seem to work after deleting.  I tried the clean followed by rebuild, including unchecking the shadow build.

Qt Creator 4.11.0

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue. Delete (or at least put it somewhere else) the ui_*.h file, and recompile the program. It fixed for me.

Answer (score 0):

sk313tOn is correct.
For shadow-build delete ui_mainwindow.h in your project directory. Because for shadow-build the correct location of ui_mainwindow.h is the build directory! ui_mainwindow.h will be build in the build directory automatically.